# How can I use Samsung Note devices' pen pressure in Chrome?

Tags: android, google-chrome, galaxy, wacom

I've seen various web apps (e.g. [Colorillo](http://colorillo.com)) that support Wacom tablet pens' pressure data by using Wacom's plugin. Chrome for Android does not support plugins, so how can I use the pen pressure of Samsung Galaxy Note devices in the browser? (Which use Wacom's digitizer technology.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to use the pen's pressure value in Chrome, but it (currently) requires that the user has a flag enabled.

Go to `chrome://flags/`, and set the "Pointer Events" setting to "Enabled". Restart Chrome when prompted.

Now, you can use the [PointerEvent API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PointerEvent) to get the pressure of the Samsung Note pen. For example, on a page with a canvas you can use:

```
['pointerdown', 'pointermove'].forEach(event => 
    yourCanvasElement.addEventListener(event, e =>
            console.log(e.pressure)
        , false));
```

Comment: PointerEvents is enabled in Chrome 55 (https://blog.chromium.org/2016/10/chrome-55-beta-input-handling.html https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4504699138998272), which shipped in December (https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2016/12/stable-channel-update-for-desktop.html).